# JavaScript Automatically Save Image File to Folder

Tags: javascript, html

How can I automatically save an image from canvas into a folder? I am using the
signature_pad-1.5.2 from `szimek` ([link](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad)). Here is what I have tried so far:

**HTML CANVAS**

```
<div id="signature-pad" class="m-signature-pad">
<div class="m-signature-pad--body">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div class="m-signature-pad--footer">
  <div class="description">Signature</div>
  <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
  <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save">Save</button>
</div>
</div>

<script src="js/signature_pad.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

The `signature_pad.js` is for drawing in the canvas. Here is the content of my app.js from signature_pad-1.5.2 (I modified it a little):

**app.js**

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad"),
clearButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=clear]"),
saveButton = wrapper.querySelector("[data-action=save]"),
canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas"),
signaturePad;

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
    alert("Please provide signature first.");
} else {
    newfolder = myObject.CreateFolder ("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\signature\\resources\\sigs");
    alert();
    saveButton.href = signaturePad.toDataURL();
    saveButton.download = 'image.png';
}
});
```

I am trying to save the `image.png` file to `newFolder` when I click the `save` button. Thanks

Comment: In general you can't, javascript doesn't have access to the clients filesystem unless a "save file" prompt is opened, and the user accepts.

Comment: Are you running this on the server side? You won't have the permissions to create a folder on your server or even on the client's local file system if this is client-side code.

Comment: Is there a way to save an image file to a folder without any prompt needed?

Comment: No, it would be a security issue if any website randomly could download and store files, create folders etc. on your filesystem.

Comment: How about I store it in the database instead? Is it a good practice?

Comment: If that works for you, sure !

Comment: What is your ultimate goal with doing this? What product/web page is this part of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way for javascript to access the filesystem, this is due to security concerns. You can store the image data as a string in a lot of places though, such as browser storage. Luckily for you it looks as though you're trying to store it in a web server's folder!

The best thing for you to do here is to make a script on the server that you want to store the image on. That script will accept a file POST request and store it in a server folder somewhere. This can be written in php for example.

Once you have that server-side script, make an AJAX request from the client (from the javascript) with the image data to that server script.

I would provide code samples and a more in-depth explanation, but unfortunately you haven't provided any real info about your tech stack and what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Good luck!

Comment: you mean, to save the image file thru the server side such as php?

Comment: @BenjaminG Exactly, the server side script will have access to the server filesystem and be able to write the image data to a file, so you have to send the image data from javascript to such a script so it can store it on the server.